# Time series resampling to a weekly interval in pandas throws error

Tags: python, pandas

I am exploring time series data (in python) and wanted to convert dates into weekly interval via pandas, but it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Data (dates.csv):

```
install_date, user, mean_level 
2015-09-09, 1, 2
2015-09-11, 2, 2
2015-09-14, 3, 5
2015-09-14, 4, 6
2015-09-20, 5, 3
2015-09-25, 6, 3
2015-09-26, 7, 1
2015-09-27, 8, 1
2015-09-27, 9, 0
2015-09-29, 10, 0
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data/dates.csv', low_memory=False)

DateData = data.resample('W').sum().head()

print(DateData)
```

Have tried couple of things around conversion of date but nothing worked and this still throws error. This is the output I need:

Output:

```
install_date, user
2015-09-09, 3
2015-09-14, 12
2015-09-25, 40
```

Thank you! Cheers.

Comment: First set the index to `install_date` and then `resample`. Use `df.set_index('install_date',inplace=True)`

Comment: Tried that as well. Gives same error.

Comment: Change the data type of `install_date` to `datetime` using `df['install_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['install_date'])` then follow the above steps.

Comment: Same error. Doesn't work. Have tried that already.

Comment: It's perfectly working for me. I am not getting any error using `pandas = 0.23.4`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Can you post the code?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381483/timeseries-resample-error-none-of-dateindex-in-column-pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the `install_date` column to `datetime` datatype then use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) using the desired rule:

```
print(df)
  install_date   user   mean_level 
0   2015-09-09      1             2
1   2015-09-11      2             2
2   2015-09-14      3             5
3   2015-09-14      4             6
4   2015-09-20      5             3
5   2015-09-25      6             3
6   2015-09-26      7             1
7   2015-09-27      8             1
8   2015-09-27      9             0
9   2015-09-29     10             0

df['install_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['install_date'])
df.dtypes()
install_date    datetime64[ns]
 user                    int64
 mean_level              int64
dtype: object
```

**Method 1:** Using the column for resampling

```
print(df.resample('7D',on='install_date').sum())

               user   mean_level 
install_date                     
2015-09-09       10            15
2015-09-16        5             3
2015-09-23       40             5
```

**Method 2:** Setting the datetime data type as index and resampling

```
df.set_index('install_date',inplace=True)
print(df.resample('7D').sum())

               user   mean_level 
install_date                     
2015-09-09       10            15
2015-09-16        5             3
2015-09-23       40             5
```

Comment: @VaibhavMagon Please [`upvote`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the solution provided your required result.