# Timeseries resample error - none of Dateindex in column pandas

Tags: pandas, time-series, resampling

Please excuse obvious errors - still in the learning process.

I am trying to do a simple timeseries plot on my data with a frequency of 15 minutes. The idea is to plot monthly means, starting with resampling data every hour - including only those hourly means that have atleast 1 observation in the interval. There are subsequent conditions for daily and monthly means.

This is relatively simpler only if this  error does not crop up- **"None of [DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01 05:00:00', '2016-01-01 05:15:00',\n....2016-12-31 16:15:00'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=103458, freq=None)] are in the [columns]"**

This is my code:

```
#Original dataframe



      Date   value
0          1/1/2016 0:00  405.22
1          1/1/2016 0:15  418.56
Date     object
value    object
dtype: object


#Conversion of 'value' column to numeric/float values.

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,errors='coerce')
year=df.Date.dt.year
df['Year'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.year )

df.value = pd.to_numeric(df.value,errors='coerce' )

Date     datetime64[ns]
value           float64
Year              int64
dtype: object
                      Date   value  Year
0      2016-01-01 00:00:00  405.22  2016
1      2016-01-01 00:15:00  418.56  2016


df=df.set_index(Date)
diurnal1 = df[df['Date']].resample('h').mean().count()>=2
**(line of error)**

diurnal_mean_1 = diurnal1.mean()[diurnal1.count() >= 1]
(the code follows)
```

Any help in solving the error will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `df=df.set_index('Date')` (Date is a string). Also I would move the conversions over into the constructor if possible after you get it working.

Comment: Thank you, Henry.